# Webpack — Images missing in build

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm having trouble using Webpack 4. When i run my project in dev mode, everything works fine. But when i build it, some images are missing (`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`).

I'm doing something wrong with the output path of the images, but i spent 48h hours trying to figure out what it is without no luck.. i hope someone can help!

Here is my `webpack.config.base.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { getEntries } = require('./utils.js');

const entries = getEntries('./src/pages/', 'js');

const config = {
  entry: Object.assign(entries, { app: './src/app.js' }),
  output: {
    pathinfo: false,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].[hash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].chunk.[chunkhash:8].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              minimize: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: './assets/[name].[md5:hash:hex:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|otf|ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: './fonts/[name].[md5:hash:hex:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|ogg|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'assets/[name].[md5:hash:hex:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  parallelism: 8,
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          name: 'commons',
          chunks: 'initial',
          minChunks: 2,
        },
        vendors: {
          chunks: 'initial',
          name: 'vendors',
          test: /node_modules\//,
          minChunks: 5,
          priority: 10,
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};

const pages = getEntries('./src/pages/', 'html');

for (const pathname in pages) {
  // Configured to generate the html file, define paths, etc.
  const conf = {
    filename: `${pathname}.html`, // html output pathname
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, `.${pages[pathname]}`), // Template path
    inject: true,
    favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/favicon.ico'),
    chunks: ['commons', 'vendors', 'app', pathname],
    chunksSortMode: 'manual',
  };
  config.plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin(conf));
}

module.exports = config;
```

My `webpack.config.prod.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const webpackConfigBase = require('./webpack.config.base.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge(webpackConfigBase, {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name].[hash:8].css',
      chunkFilename: 'css/[id].[hash:8].css',
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], { root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../') }),
  ],
});
```

And finally my webpack.config.dev.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const portfinder = require('portfinder');
const webpackConfigBase = require('./webpack.config.base.js');

const webpackConfigDev = webpackMerge(webpackConfigBase, {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    port: 8080,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: 1000,
    },
    stats: {
      children: false,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name].css',
      chunkFilename: 'css/[id].css',
    }),
  ],
});

module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  portfinder.basePort = 8080;
  portfinder.getPort((err, port) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      webpackConfigDev.devServer.port = port;
      resolve(webpackConfigDev);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i've figured out what was going wrong here. 
I had a problem with my `MiniCssExtractPlugin` filenames and chunkFilenames. My images output path was actually not `dist/assets/myimage` but `dist/css/assets/myimage`, so it was looking at the wrong folder when building!

I modified it from this :

```js
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'css/[name].[hash:8].css',
    chunkFilename: 'css/[id].[hash:8].css',
})
```

to this

```js
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '[name].[hash:8].css',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash:8].css',
}),
```